# How do I add a shortcut to add a modifier to an object?

Tags: customization, shortcut

Is there a way to assign key-binding for add some modifier to selected object? For example boolean modifier? In the Input preferences setting I can not find any appropriate item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with a lot of things in blender, you do this by right-clicking on a menu item and choosing *Add Shortcut*. In this instance, open the *Add Modifier* menu (the menu found on objects where you choose which modifier to add), right-click on the modifier you want to add a shortcut to, choose *Add Shortcut* and then press the keys you want to assign to the modifier:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to do this via the *User Preferences* you can go to the *Input* tab of the preferences, open the *3D View*> *Object Mode* category and click *Add New*.

In the operator id box you put `object.modifier_add` as this is the command that is triggered when adding a modifier. You can then select the type of modifier you want to add from the *Type* dropdown box and then of course specify the keys you want for this shortcut:

[image]