# How to add window specific shortcuts?

Tags: windows

The steps explained here by Ray Mairlot for how to add custom shortcuts to pretty much anything in Blender are easy to understand:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63125/50625
But I would like to do all of this, but limit the new shortcut to a specific window, just like how most of Blender's other default shortcuts work.

In my case, I want to make custom key bindings for controlling the animation timeline.
I want to stop/start with SPACE, for example, but I don't want to un-bind the default search box that normally appears when pressing space everywhere else.

Thanks

Comment: "*do you not prefer that new users to add to existing questions*" No, if you have a different question post it has a separate post. Link to the original one  if it is relevant.

Comment: I was only asking because I felt like it was not a different question, but a continuation on the information already there.
There are so many forums that will blast you to pieces for "spamming" with already existing questions.

Comment: We do not have the mechanisms for you to ask in another person's question. You either have to post a comment there, which will most likely go largely unnoticed, or get you pointed towards posting a new question at best. Or you would have to (mistakenly) post an answer, which your promptly be deleted and again recommend you post a new question instead. But thanks for actually caring, most newcomers don't even bother. Do go through our [help section](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help) to get acquainted with the local rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question regarding comments, check this out:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead.

To add the <kbd>Space</kbd> control for playing and pausing your animation in the timeline, that can be done by opening the *User Preferences* and going to the input tab. Find the *Timeline* and click the little arrow to expand it. Then click *Add New* to create a new shortcut. Set the control to be *Keyboard* and set the key to <kbd>Space</kbd>, then set the operator to be ***screen.animation_play***. I found the operator by searching for <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and using the *Key Binding* search, then copy pasting the operator. Since this is a timeline specific key binding, all other <kbd>Space</kbd> shortcuts will still work.

Comment: That's wonderful!
Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!
I really love how customize-able Blender is.

Searching for key-binds like that was a great tip!
Is it possible to search for "ALT+A"?
When I press ALT+A it is registering the "A" but not "ALT"


Yes about the comments, the very first point there:
"There are big problems with spam. Automated filters cannot catch all of it"
That is exactly why I was asking, because isn't it even worse to have bots spam out NEW threats rather than "just" spamming comments?
I'm genuinely asking, I'm not trying to argue :)

Thanks again!

Comment: Oh yes!
I can just literally TYPE "ALT".

Haha this is so great!

Comment: This isn't the place to discuss how SE sites are run, so I can't comment on that. The linked question did have some decent info though, and you can try looking around on that site for answers to questions in that area.